# Umbraco console app to change the name and link of a document without publishing all children

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I've written a console app using the Umbraco (7.1.4) contentService API to move some nodes and rename them in a site redesign. It all works fine except when I rename the document the 'Link to Document' doesn't change. The code is adapted from https://github.com/sitereactor/umbraco-console-example.

```
private static void MoveNode(IContentService contentService, int nodeId, int newParentId, string newname)
    {
        //Get the Root Content
        var nodeContent = contentService.GetByIds(nodeId.AsEnumerableOfOne()).First();
        nodeContent.Name = newname;                
        contentService.Move(nodeContent, newParentId);
        var status = contentService.SaveAndPublishWithStatus(nodeContent);
        Console.WriteLine(status);
    }
```

Status is True and the page name is changed when I look at it in back office but the 'Link to Document' doesn't change. Now if I use

```
var status = contentService.PublishWithChildrenWithStatus(nodeContent);
```

Then it works but takes a lot longer (minutes), but if I change the name in back office then it only takes seconds but the links are updated correctly. Is there another way to rename a document without Publishing all the children?

(I've left out a bit of code in the above - sometimes it moves sometimes it just renames, but in either case I have to publish with the children to get it to work.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this happens because the XML cache file has not been updated.

Have a look here for a few ways of doing it
http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/api-cheatsheet/publishing-and-republishing

Or the quickest is just delete APP_Data\umbraco.config - the XML cache file, probably not recommended for Prod but gets things working quickly in dev.